# Best practice for waiting for image processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, backgroundworker, carrierwave

I've got a model that uses Carrierwave and CarrierwaveBackgrounder for image processing:

```
mount_uploader :background, BackgroundUploader
process_in_background :background
```

So when an resource gets created I would like to wait for the Backgrounder to finish processing the image and then redirect to the newly created resource.

All I can think of now seems very dirty to me:

```
sleep(2.0) while @page.background.large.file.exists?
```

But that could maybe even cause timeouts.

Any other/better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@page.process_background_upload = true` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of going into trouble of installing and using an additional plugin to process your images in the background and then go into more trouble to reverse all the background effects.

So, the best practice to "wait for image processing" is not to use one in the first place when you don't need it (IMHO).

Comment: Well, in general it should all be processed in the background. This is just a special case which makes it a bit complicated. But good point, I'm going to check if CarrierwaveBackgrounder can do stuff not in background.